# Can't trigger function from NSTimer's selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, nstimer

So here's my code :

```
- (IBAction)run:(id)sender {

    animationPointer = 0;

    self.animationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    UIView *allViews = [[UIView alloc]
        initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.paths count]; i++) {

        [allViews addSubview:[self createAnimation:[self.paths objectAtIndex:i]]];

        [self.animationArray addObject:allViews];
    }

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(animateTurn)
        userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

- (void)animateTurn {
    UIView *tempView = [self.animationArray objectAtIndex:animationPointer];
    [self.view addSubview:tempView];
    for (UIImageView *view in tempView.subviews) {
        [[tempView.subviews objectAtIndex:animationPointer] startAnimating];
    }

    animationPointer++;

    if (animationPointer >= [self.animationArray count]) {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

`createAnimation` returns, as you would expect, a fully animated `UIImageView`.  The plan is to have several on each `UIView` and then animate them all on a `UIView` then the next after half a second and it repeats.  There's only one on each `UIView` for now.

However, when calling animateTurn on the `NSTimer`, the animations don't show up.
If I call the method via the normal `[self animateTurn]` then they appear but nothing with `NSTimer` nor the `performSelector` function.

Any help with this (or even suggestions for a better method)?

**EDIT:**
I should mention the function is actually being triggered and the code is being run including the startAnimating (checked with BOOL/NSLog).  There is simply nothing being shown.

Comment: You should check whether the method is called on the main thread.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Include this line after your timer:-

```
    [timer fire];
```

Comment: Can you explain why this worked or what this should do? This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @imartin, You can use this method to fire a repeating timer without interrupting its regular firing schedule. If the timer is non-repeating, it is automatically invalidated after firing, even if its scheduled fire date has not arrived. For reference refer this    https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/fire

Comment: @hussainShabbir Thanks, but I understand what `-fire` does. The problem was, that the timer was not firing at all (what I understood from the question) and I don't know how can manual fire fix such problem.

Comment: @imartin, you are right this was not the root cause, it was only fix. For root cause we need to analyze the method, in which thread it is executing :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is Your Solution:-

This is what I used and now the selector is Working. :-)

```
  if (![NSThread isMainThread]) 
    { [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(selectorToRunInMainThread) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]; 
     }
 -(void)selectorToRunInMainThread
{
 NSString *str = @"Timer event has fired"; 
NSTimer *atimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateModel:) userInfo:str repeats:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: Here's the thing.  First, [NSthread isMainThread] returns true even when in a method called by selector...YET calling performSelectorOnMainThread with animateTurn manages to make it work... BUT after moving the animation code to another method and calling it with NStimer once again produced nothing.  Something odd is going on.